# Understanding continuous variable entropy

Tags: continuous-data, entropy, mutual-information

I am struggling to understand continuous variable entropies and mutual informations for 2 or more variables. Consider 2D normal distribution $\rho(x,y)$ defined as follows

$$X\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_x^2)$$
$$\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_\epsilon^2)$$
$$Y = X + \epsilon$$

Then the covariance matrix of $\rho(x,y)$ is

$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^2_x & \sigma^2_x \\ \sigma^2_x & \sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_\epsilon \end{pmatrix}$$
and its determinant $|\Sigma| = \sigma^2_x \sigma^2_\epsilon$. Further, standard expressions can be used for marginal and 2D entropies

$$H(X) = \frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi e \sigma^2_x$$

$$H(Y) = \frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi e (\sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_\epsilon)$$

$$H(XY) = \frac{1}{2}\log 4\pi^2 e^2 |\Sigma| = \frac{1}{2}\log 4\pi^2 e^2 \sigma^2_x \sigma^2_\epsilon$$

and the mutual information

$$I(X:Y) = \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{\sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_\epsilon}{\sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

So $Y$ is a noisy version of $X$. As the noise variance $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ gets smaller, the joint entropy $H(X,Y)$ goes to negative infinity and the mutual information goes to positive infinity. How should these quantities be interpreted? It appears that my intuition from discrete information theory does not hold. From discrete information theory I would expect the mutual information to be bounded by the largest of the two entropies, but that apparently is not the case. What quantities do differential entropy and mutual information measure, and how are they conceptually related to each other.